# Logarithmic-like growth with a limit

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, curves, mathematical-modeling, logistic-regression

I'm creating a curve that needs to have logarithmic-like growth but has a limit of 1. Logistic growth does not make sense in the context of my problem, and something like $P(x) = 1-e^{-bx}$ or a Hill function produces too severe an "elbow". What sort of function could I use for this issue? Alternatively, what tuning parameters would soften the curves of a Hill function or exponential or similar?

Comment: Are you restricting yourself to the positive quadrant?  If so I would reccomend something like $$\frac{x^2}{a+x^2}  - b$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you mean by "logarith-like growth", but for the Hill function, wikipedia would seem to show that you can adjust the parameter $n$, and then shift the function over to the point where the "elbow" occurs to make it look more like a logarithm with its concavity. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_(biochemistry)#Hill_coefficient)

Comment: When I mean logarithmic-like growth, I mean the curve is smoother with a less pronounced elbow than I'm finding in other functions. It is not so much where the elbow is located as how pronounced it looks.

Comment: Something like a [Gompertz Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function) perhaps? I'm still not sure how a Hill curve with appropriately small $n$ isn't smooth enough. On the wikipedia page, near the top there is a graph showing that while varying $n$ we get things looking from between linear (small $n$) to nearly a step function (large $n$)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ivr1bldwwl) I created for a previous question. You can play with the values of $a$ and $b$ using the sliders on the left side. You might find something you like there.